# How to reshape LSTM input

Tags: python, dataframe, deep-learning, lstm, reshape

I have data with 2833 rows, 6 features and 8 labels
then I divide the data into training and testing based on labels.
On LSTM modeling, I got the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 11874 into shape (1979,64,6)
```

here is my code:

```
df_raw_primer = pd.read_excel(path_data)

# Get unique label
unique_labels = df_raw_primer['label'].unique()
split_factor=0.7
train_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_raw_primer.columns)
test_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_raw_primer.columns)

unique_lengths = {}
for uni in unique_labels:
  unique_lengths[uni] = int(len(df_raw_primer[df_raw_primer.label == uni]) * split_factor)

for uni in unique_labels:
  for _, row in df_raw_primer.iterrows():
    if(row['label'] == uni):
      if(unique_lengths[uni]):  # if unique klength is not equal to 0
        train_data = train_data.append({'label': row['label'],
                                          'gyro x': row['gyro x'], 
                                          'gyro y': row['gyro y'], 
                                          'gyro z': row['gyro z'], 
                                          'acc x': row['acc x'], 
                                          'acc y': row['acc y'], 
                                          'acc z': row['acc z']},
                                         ignore_index=True)
        unique_lengths[uni] = unique_lengths[uni] - 1  # minus unique lengths value
      else:
        test_data = test_data.append({'label': row['label'],
                                          'gyro x': row['gyro x'], 
                                          'gyro y': row['gyro y'], 
                                          'gyro z': row['gyro z'], 
                                          'acc x': row['acc x'], 
                                          'acc y': row['acc y'], 
                                          'acc z': row['acc z']},
                                         ignore_index=True)          
                                         
sliceInput_train_data = train_data.iloc[:, 0:-1]
sliceTarget_train_label = train_data['label']
sliceInput_test_data = test_data.iloc[:, 0:-1]
sliceTarget_test_label = test_data['label']

# fit and evaluate a model
def evaluate_model(trainX, trainy, testX, testy):
    verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 15, 64
    n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = 64, 6, 8
    model = Sequential() 
    model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(attention(return_sequences=False)) # receive 3D and output 2D
    model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
    model.summary()
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    # fit network
    model.fit(trainX, trainy, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
    # evaluate model
    loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(testX, testy, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
    attention_weights = model.layers[3].get_weights()[0]
    heat_map = sb.heatmap(attention_weights)
    pyplot.show()
    return accuracy

# summarize scores
def summarize_results(scores):
    print(scores)
    m, s = mean(scores), std(scores)
    print('Accuracy: %.3f%% (+/-%.3f)' % (m, s))

# run an experiment
def run_experiment(repeats=10):
    trainX, trainy, testX, testy = sliceInput_train_data, sliceTarget_train_label, sliceInput_test_data, sliceTarget_test_label 
    trainX = np.array(trainX)
    trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 64, trainX.shape[1]))
    scores = list()
    for r in range(repeats):
        score = evaluate_model(trainX, trainy, testX, testy)
        score = score * 100.0
        print('&gt;#%d: %.3f' % (r+1, score))
        scores.append(score)
    # summarize results
    summarize_results(scores)
    
run_experiment()
```

I'm really confused, I don’t know where 11874 came from whereas my shape data for trainX is
print(trainX.shape) = (1979, 6)
is there a problem with my data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your data from dataFrames to numpy arrays.  Check the shape of your data and utilize the outputs accordingly...

EDIT:

```
trainX = np.array(trainX)

trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (x, y, z))
```

x, y, and z are stand-ins for the shape of the data you would like.  You can access specific components such as:

```
trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 64, trainX.shape[1]))
```

This being said, typically input_shape is given with square brackets [] which MAY be affecting things but you definitely need a numpy array of training data and not a pandas dataFrame to see much success in any machine learning programs.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I tried like your suggestion, and changed method def run_experiment(repeats=10) like this:
 trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX[0], 64, trainX[1]))
 trainy = np.reshape(trainy, (trainy[0], 64, trainy[1]))
 testX = np.reshape(testX, (testX[0], 64, testX[1]))
 testy = np.reshape(testy, (testy[0], 64, testy[1]))
but i get an error like this:
KeyError: 0

Comment: I edited my answer just now.  It should be trainX.shape[0]

Comment: Thank you again for your help but now i got this error: 
cannot reshape array of size 11874 into shape (1979,64,6). I don't know where 11874 came from. Is there something wrong with my data?

Comment: Try first converting your training data to an array: trainX = np.array(trainX) then reshape

Comment: shape data after dividing into train and test:
print(train_data.shape) = (1979, 7) --- 
print(test_data.shape) = (854, 7) --- 

shape data when split into features and labels
print(trainX.shape) = (1979, 6) --- 
print(trainy .shape) = (1979,) --- 
print(testX .shape) = (854, 6) --- 
print(testy.shape) = (854,)

Comment: I've tried to add the following code: 
trainX = np.array(trainX) ---
trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 64, trainX.shape[1])) --- 
but the error still appears on the line:
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 11874 into shape (1979,64,6)

Comment: Please edit your question with the changes you have made so far.  I'd like to ensure they are going in the right place.

Comment: I edited my question just now. Thank you and please help me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239560/discussion-between-zen-and-apin-pipin).